# AngularJS D3JS Donut chart colour change of arc on hover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, donut-chart

I am  creating donut using `d3.js` with `AngularJS`. Here is my [Donut](https://plnkr.co/edit/9eUY7UyS5jVzcH98),  by default I need to have same color for all the arcs of Donut chart,  which is working fine. Now on  hover of the particular arc I need to change the color of that particular arc to blue, which is not working. Can any one help me in this?

Below is the answer from the refernce plunker provided. :

```
 scope.mouseOverPath = function(d) {

          d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .style("fill", "blue")
            .each("start", function(d) {
              labelRadius = radius + chartConfig.labelPaddingOver;
              d3.select(this.parentNode).select('.legend')
                .transition()
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                  var c = arc.centroid(d),
                    x = c[0],
                    y = c[1],
                    height = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                  return "translate(" + (x / height * labelRadius) + ',' +
                    (y / height * labelRadius) + ")";
                });
            })
```

...
}

```
scope.mouseOutPath = function(d) {

          d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .style('fill', function(d) {
              return color(d.data.label);
            })
            .each("start", function(d) {

              labelRadius = radius + chartConfig.labelPadding;


              d3.select(this.parentNode).select('.legend')
                .transition()
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                  var c = arc.centroid(d),
                    x = c[0],
                    y = c[1],
                    height = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                  return "translate(" + (x / height * labelRadius) + ',' +
                    (y / height * labelRadius) + ")";
                });

 
           })
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using d3's `style` method inside your directive's `scope.mouseOverPath` and `scope.mouseOutPath` methods did the trick.

https://plnkr.co/edit/P98rPVKOHOgN5fKB